# How to handle response sending in case of listeners on nodejs child process to avoid double response sending attempt

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

I am using Express and nodejs child_process to make a request to a blogFeedPage, scrape it through a child process and to send back to the Client a JSON representation of the blog content.
The snippet of code below shows how at the moment I am handling the response to the Client and I don't know what's the best way to handle the 'exit' and 'error' events from the child process. My primary concern is about double attempt of sending response but I would like also to avoid the Client waiting with no answer.

```
  request.get({ url: blogUrl }, function (err, res, blogFeedPage) {
if (err) return next({ status: 502, message: 'error while trying to contact the blog feed server' })

var child = childProcess.fork(__dirname + '/child.js')

child.on('message', function (blogFeeds) {
  child.kill()
  if (!blogFeeds || blogFeeds && blogFeeds.error) {
    return next({ status: 503, message: 'Error while trying to parse the blog feed' })
  }
  clientRes.sendSuccess(200, 'success', blogFeeds)
  res.status(200).send({ status: 'success', data: blogFeeds })
})

child.on('exit', function (code, signal) {
  // ??? send response to the Client if not already sent
  child.kill()
})

child.on('error', function (error) {
  // ??? send response to the Client if not already sent
  child.kill()
})

child.send({ html: blogFeedPage })
```

Comment: Why not introduce a local variable to keep track of the progress? Set it to true if the response is already sent.

Comment: Thanks @JonasKöritz but that's not such an elegant solution.

Comment: You could also aggregate the response on each message event in a local variable, then send everything collected on exit.

Answer (score 0):

Do not kill the child on message, save the blogFeeds outside of the calblack instead. Then send the message on exit. If you want to impose a timeout on the child process initialize an empty result first and kill the child after your timeout expires. Exit will get fired and your empty result can be delivered (or an error message).